# JWT getHeader return null

Tags: rest, api, spring-boot, jwt

When I send a token it works, but when I send a request to receive data the function getheader() returns null.

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    //recuperer de la requete envoyer dans jwt le header du token
    String jwt =request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
    System.out.println("authori");
    System.out.println(jwt);
    if(jwt==null ) {
        //faire le filtre 
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
    Claims claims=Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(SecurityConstants.SECRET)//signer avec le secret
            //parser et remplace le TOKEN_PREFIX par chaine vide
            .parseClaimsJws(jwt.replaceAll(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
            //recuper le corps du token
            .getBody();

     String username =claims.getSubject();
     //returne tableau d'objet qui contient les roles du user
     ArrayList<Map<String,String>> roles=(ArrayList<Map<String,String>>) claims.get("role");
     Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<>();
     //parcourire et recuperer les role de mon token
     roles.forEach(r->{
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.get("authority"))); 
     });
     //mettre dans authenticatedUserToken le nom et authoriter d'un utilisateur authentifier dans le token 
     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken  authenticatedUserToken=
             new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,null,authorities);
     //charger l'identiter dans le context de l'application
     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUserToken);
     filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } 

}
```

this is from securConfigure

```
http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))

    .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

**Here I sent authentification everything ok I get my token:**

[image]

**Here I try to get service:**

[image]

**Here what test console in JWTAuthorization display where I call `resquest.getHeader()`**

[image]

Comment: In your Authorization header there should be a space between `bearer` and the token. In your screenshots I see `bearereyJh....`, instead of `bearer eyJh....`

Comment: I added the space but it gave nothing you do not know anything else that can be the solution to my problem thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your endpoint it looks like http://localhost:8080/tasks is authenticating with JWT(its being passed in correctly and authenticated).

The response headers to ./tasks should not include the Header "Authorization"  in it's response...I don't see why you would need this after authentication.